# defineProperty to array item on Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, defineproperty

The problem with array defined elements. After clear all data, elements still exist in array, but length of array returns **0** value. When trying to fill array again, we are didn't see, that array is empty.

I was trying to clear array different ways

```
arr.splice(0, arr.length);

arr.length = 0;

etc...
```

but array always have old values after last element was removed from array...

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/h1mj6729/11/) is example

What am I doing wrong?

It happens only latest versions on Chrome browser, in other browsers all is ok.

working on 35.0.1916.153 m, but NOT working on 37.0.2062.94 m.

I've also created a ticket in chromium tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408918).

Comment: It looks like deleting the array element doesn't remove the `getter` for that element.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I reproduced it.

Comment: Does it need the loop? Can you please reduce the offending code to a minimal example (`defineProperty`+`delete`+`assignment`+`empting`+`length checking` or so, not `watch` and `clear` and `fill` methods), and post that into your question?

Comment: @Bergi yes, it need the loop. fill, clear, fill again.

Comment: have you tried to override it ? like arr = new array();

Comment: @Dwza no, it's bad, i need old link to array. When call arr = [], it just create new array in current scope. but other scopes, where arr using have old links to array. i think this is problem with memory of Chromium, but maybe i'm not right.

Comment: **UPDATE**

I also thought about `Object.observe` method in the latest Chrome, and made a wrapper for my problem

see update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h1mj6729/12/)